# Error When Clicking on 'Edit' For Steps in Jobs

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Every once in a while, after I've clicked on 'Edit' for steps on several SQL Agent jobs, I'll get the below error message.

[image]

When I exit and reopen SSMS, the errors stop appearing.  Anyone know what is causing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is fixed in 2008 SP3 and in 2008 R2 SP1

Connect link is http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/557402/ssms-can-no-longer-create-or-edit-job-steps